# dcfldd do trunc files when conv=notrunc

Tags: file, dd

I want to work with dcfldd becouse it is faster and modern disks are bigger.

dcfldd trunc file even if the option conv=notrunc is set.   I work on CentOs5.x.
Also, I tryed to compile the program from source but it gives the same results,  dcfldd corrupts the file.

examples:

```
echo -n 123456789 >outfile

echo -n "X" | dd of=outfile conv=notrunc
```

cat outfile will give:

```
X23456789

echo -n "Y" | dcfldd of=outfile conv=notrunc
```

cat outfile will give:

```
Y
```

Should I change something in the source or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, `of` is only affected by `seek` and `conv` options that appear before them. So your example:

```
echo -n 123456789 >outfile
echo -n "Y" | dcfldd conv=notrunc of=outfile
```

will work as intended. The behavior may be modified to accommodate `dcfldd`'s ability to deal with multiple `of` options.